# Unable to store result value from a tesseract function to a global variable inside an asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, tesseract, puppeteer, tesseract.js, asynchronous-javascript

I'm using tesseract JS to convert an image into text format. The conversion is successful and I'm able to print it out in the console. But I am unable to get this text outside the scope of the function.

I have tried assigning the text to a global variable and then printing it but nothing happens.

```
(async () => {

tesseract.process('new.png', (err, text) => {
    if(err){return console.log("An error occured: ", err); }
    console.log("Recognized text:",text);
    });

})();
```

Need to be able to get the value of text outside the function and use it again in another asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use asynchronous operations, like `Promise`, `callback`, `async-await` you cannot use synchronous flow anymore.

Think it like this, Asynchronous functions are operations that will be completed in future, you want some value out of it then you CANNOT get the value untill the first asynchronous function is completed.

That being said, you `CAN` use `Promises` (seem) like synchronous functions if you use `aysnc-await`, IF you don't want to use Promise chain. So you need to promisify the `tesseract.process` function:

```
const utils = require('util');

(async () => {
  const tessProcess = utils.promisify(tesseract.process);
  try {
    const text = await tessProcess('new.png');
    console.log("Recognized text:", text);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("An error occured: ", err);
  }
})();
```

**EDIT:** After checking the code snippet:

```
const utils = require('util');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  const tessProcess = utils.promisify(tesseract.process);
  await page.setViewport(viewPort)
  await page.goto('example.com')
  await page.screenshot(options)
  const text = await tessProcess('new.png');
  //YOU CAN USE text HERE/////////////
  await page.$eval('input[id=companyID]', (el, value) => el.value = value, text);//here too

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: so is it not possible to store this text value in another variable and use it again in another function?

Comment: Yes only after the first function is completely executed. Otherwise it will be null. You should check out resources about asynchronous functions.

Comment: But if you can specify in the question how exactly do you want to use the text in the function then i may able to help.

Comment: here is a code snippet, where I take a screenshot of a captcha with puppeteer and proceed to solve it with tesseract. Now I want to use this processed text to enter in the captcha input field again to submit the form. https://jsfiddle.net/df7bnk2h/2/

Comment: Edited the answer, you can use `text` in the `page.$eval` function

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to puppeteer, I used this   await page.$eval('input[id=userEnteredCaptcha]', el => el.value = text);
to type the text but now it says that text is undefined. Is the syntax wrong here?

Comment: can you console log the `text` before page.$eval and check if text is coming or not?

Comment: It is coming up

Comment: It is correct, but you can use `await page.$eval('input[id=companyID]', (el, value) => el.value = value, text)` to check